# How to execute same job cocurrently in Spring xd

Tags: spring-xd

We have the below requirement,

1. In spring xd, we have a job lets assume the job name as MyJob
2. which will be invoked by another process using the rest service of spring xd, lets assume process name as OutsideProcess (non-spring xd process).
3. OutsideJob invokes MyJob when ever a file added to a location (lets assume FILES_LOC) to which OutsideJob is listening.

In this scenario, lets assume that MyJob takes 5minutes to complete the job.

1. At 10:00 AM, there is a file copied to FILES_LOC, then OutsideProcess will trigger MyJob immediately. (approximately it will be completed at 10:05AM)
2. At 10:01 AM, another file copied to FILES_LOC, then OutsideProcess will trigger one more instance of MyJob at 10:01AM. But the second instance is getting queued and starts the execution once the first instance completes its execution (approximately at 10:05AM).

If we invoke the different jobs at the same time they are getting executed concurrenctly, but the same job multiple instances are not getting executed concurrenctly.

Please let me know how can I execute the same job with multiple instances concurrently.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is dynamic deployment of the job and triggering it right away. You can use SpringXD Rest template to create the job definition on the fly and launch them after sleeping a few seconds. And make sure you undeploy/destroy the job when the job completes successfully.

Another solution could be to create a few module instances of your job with different names and use them as your  slave processes. You can query status of these job module instances and launch the one that is finished or queue the one that is least recently launched.

Remember you can run jobs with partition support if applicable. This way you will finish your job faster and be able to run more jobs.